# Airport / airline data from all over the world

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, companies, aviation

Where can I get a database with airports and possible with (available / closed) runways from all over the world?

I am looking for airlines and contact info of managers in decision-making positions at airlines too.

Answer (score 15):

A quick google search found me the data page of [OpenFlights.org](http://openflights.org/data.html). This page has a free (donation request) CSV file with 8000+ airports: [LINK](https://sourceforge.net/p/openflights/code/HEAD/tree/openflights/data/airports.dat?format=raw).

OpenFlights.org points to [OurAirports.com](http://ourairports.com/), which provides extensive CSV downloads with data being in the public domain. See their [data page](http://ourairports.com/data/).

---

Regarding **contact info for airport management**, the FAA provides this info for US airports: [LINK](http://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/airportdata_5010/). Use this form to filter and then scroll down to the download section:

[image]

Here is a direct link to the [Airport Facilities](http://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/airportdata_5010/menu/nfdcfacilitiesexport.cfm?Region=&District=&State=&County=&City=&Use=&Certification=) Excel file (6.5 MB). Screenshot below. Lots of contact info when you scroll right.

[image]

There is also a '[download data](http://nfdc.faa.gov/portal/index.jsp)' link but it requires registration.

Answer (score 12):

[OurAirports.com](http://ourairports.com/) is, in my experience, the best data set publicly available. You may find ICAO or IATA missing or outdated here or there, but it's rare (in my experience). They have also categorized the airports as Main or Small, etc, which is particularly helpful, although for the USA, you can simply filter the ICAO code by 'starts with' K and that gets you pretty close as well. Geonames dot org has airport data, and perhaps they may fill some gaps internationally.

OurAirports.com data has been loaded into [Freebase](https://www.freebase.com/), from my understanding, but the top level data in Freebase is still yet to fully be populated. In other words, OurAirports is more accurate. -- and far more thorough. It's been awhile since I've looked at the Freebase data, so I can't be certain. Here is a Google Fusion table of the OurAirports set, which is where I found it initially 5 years ago -- since then I maintain mine internally. I am very glad I found it. Their website states they have 46,055 active airports in the set, and Fusion Tables only has 44077, so I venture to guess Fusion Tables is out of date --> at least, [here it may be](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S334585OmZp). I think X-Plane data was also very good, if i remember correctly. WELT2000 looks to be useful for smaller strips and waypoints.

You can also take Wikipedia's URL and add the name of the airport (for most major airports) to get to it:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centennial_Airport
```

Similarly, you can do the same for [Acukwik](http://www.acukwik.com/) or [Airnav.com](https://www.airnav.com/), among many other sites catering to general aviation.

A new one that seems useful for reasons I am less familiar with is [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/), offering a nice user interface and [some cool maps](https://skyvector.com/airport/APA/Centennial-Airport).

[Flightaware](http://flightaware.com/) is also doing an admirable job of bulking up their directory of [services and aircraft data](http://www.flightaware.com/resources/airport/KAPA).

The best place to look for aircraft is the FAA's registry, in terms of aircraft in the US. The [website](http://www.privatejetcharteradvisors.com/airports/centennial-airport-kapa-apa) seems a work in progress but buried inside are tidy listings for airport services, such as Fixed Base Operators (FBOs), catering and ground transportation specific to the airport. Combining the airport name and keywords from the domain seems to get you there, as the internal site navigation is lacking.

On the topic of private jet charter and helicopters, the defacto public source seems to be [AirCharterGuide.com](http://aircharterguide.com/). If open data downloads are what you are after, OurAirports.com is solid, [Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) may offer some interesting data and I believe the FAA data is open public, but the way they allow download of the tables makes a trick of relating it properly, if I remember correctly.

---

*I had to go back thru and breakup a bunch of these links since I am new here and only have authority to include a couple, which are the two more difficult ones to locate. Hopefully, someone finds this helpful and I look forward to seeing others suggestions too. I am interested in finding data on aircraft outside the US and their associated model information.

** Aside - I've expounded upon the original question as I interpret the real issue at hand is a need to gather sufficient information about airports and decision makers to create a dataset valuable enough to "do" or accomplish something... and often times that might be related to businesses on sales missions, as such, scrounging from all available data sources may be needed as points of contact and decision makers are best accessed by connecting with the airport community as a whole, particularly in smaller airports which are the majority, especially if charter "airlines" are of interest -- sometimes airline operators cross both charter and commercial markets -- in addition to medical and cargo.

Answer (score 7):

Another source of airport information around the world is the UN Economic Commission for Europe (UNECE) dataset of United Nations Code for Trade and Transport Locations (UN/LOCODE). These cover major transport terminals: air, sea, land, etc.

A link to the data is here:

http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/welcome.html

I also have a tutorial I wrote awhile back ago on using this dataset:

http://opengeocode.org/tutorials/LOCODE.php

Answer (score 6):

Focusing more on the spatial data - but other attributes may be available, you can check:

[OurAirports](http://www.ourairports.com/data/) - data available as KML, CSV, with an  rss feed of comments describing facilities and current operations

[World Aeronautical Database](http://worldaerodata.com/) - Not sure how accessible the data is

[USSTRATCOM Worldwide Airports](http://gapspub.ultra-prologic.com/POIRSS/default.ashx?source=Worldwide_Airports) - GeoRSS feed; I think the source data is the old Digital Aeronautical Flight Information (DAFIF)

[X-Plane](http://data.x-plane.com/get_data.html) -includes runways taxiway layouts; .dat file designed to work with x-plane flight simulator.  Source of TerraGear airports in their landcover database

[WELT2000](http://www.segelflug.de/vereine/welt2000/)- free global OBDL database of airports, airfields, waypoints, Glider Sites, Ultralight Sites; Releases published twice a year: beginning of February and August. Snapshots published daily; downloads are txt files

Answer (score 0):

aviowiki.com has over 60,000 worldwide airports, continually managed by an in-house team of aviation professionals.

All the data is available to view online at app.aviowiki.com and is available via API too.