# Publicly Available (Free) Flight Data

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for data on international flight patterns. Similar to the data used in the paper

http://currents.plos.org/outbreaks/article/assessing-the-international-spreading-risk-associated-with-the-2014-west-african-ebola-outbreak/

except they seem to have used a paid service to obtain the data. Is it possible to get free data of flight records that is fairly recent (within the last few months)?

Comment: You may find some of what you're looking for in the answers to this question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/airport-airline-data-from-all-over-the-world

Comment: I'm not convinced anyone would give away or sell *flight pattern* data as it could be used by terrorists and enemies. Do you want lists of daily flight patterns, or more general "common flight lanes"?