# Airline check for availability data

Tags: data-request, api, transportation

Where can I find a free web service, or data available in XML format, to check for *flights availability*?  Something like [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) to which provides airport data.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a free source of this information. I have heard that that ExpertFlyer.com can provide an API but it's for volume users. Also, Google's https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search has a field for this in their response (`bookingCodeCount`) and gives you 50 free queries per day.

Comment: You might also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680408/is-there-any-api-for-getting-flight-fare - fare information will usually have the # of seats available

Answer (score 1):

Just thought this might help anyone... https://www.airport-data.com/api/doc.php also provides API. you might have to sign up but its free. data is not real-time, so not to be used for flight travel

Comment: this seems to have airport and aircraft info, but nothing related to flights. It would be an appropriate answer here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3850/1511